# A rectangle is divided up in the diagram below. How many rectangles exist in this diagram?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

A rectangle is divided up in the diagram below.  How many rectangles exist in this diagram?

The grid is 8 by 12

Comment: I'M TRYING TO HELP YOU BUT FIRST I HAVE TO FIX MY CAPS LACK WHAT IF THE GRID WAS 2 BY 3 THOUGH...

Comment: I don't see any diagram!

Comment: I cant post or make the diagram so i said what its dimensions were

Answer (score 1):

If you consider a square is a rectangle then the formula of calculating the number of rectangles in a grid is:
$$\frac{m(m+1)(n)(n+1)}{4}$$
And the answer to your question is:
$$\frac{8(8+1)(12)(12+1)}{4}=2808$$

Comment: It would be better to show where the formula comes from, choosing two horizontal lines and two vertical lines from those available.